# XML parsing with LINQ, has 2 tags with the same name but different level and not always has a value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I have the following XML:

```
   <request>
       <book>
          <id>1833801</id>
          <title>The Yiddish Policemen's Union   </title> 
           <work>
               <id>1234</id>
               <name/>
           </work>
           <similar_books>
              <book><id>243859</id><title>Stations of Tide</title>                           <isbn>0380817616</isbn>
                 <authors><author><id>14454</id><name>Michael Swanwick</name></author>            </authors>
              </book>
          </similar_books>
          <authors>
              <author>
         <id>2715</id><name>Michael Chabon</name>
           <ratings_count>215884</ratings_count></author>
          </authors>
          <popular_shelves>
         <shelf name="jewish" count="104"/><shelf name="sci-fi" count="100"/>                   
         </popular_shelves>
       </book>                
     </request>
```

I want to have all tags with their respective values, and I am using following code:

```
           HttpWebRequest oReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriRoot);

                    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)oReq.GetResponse();
                    log.Info(" (ISBN= " + isbn10 + ") Http request has response.");

                    if (resp.ContentType.StartsWith("application/xml", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        Stream resultStreamISBN = resp.GetResponseStream();
                        Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"); //encoding for non-latin chars
                        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(resultStreamISBN, encode);

        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(responseReader.ReadToEnd());
        var books = (from u in xdoc.Descendants().Elements("book")
                     select new
                     {

                         id = (string)u.Element("title"),
                         title = (string)u.Element("title"),               
                         works = (from i in u.Elements("work")
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      work_best_book_id = (int)i.Element("id"),
                                      work_name = (string)i.Element("name"),

                                  }).ToList(),
                          authors = (from i in u.Elements("authors").Elements("author")
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        id = (int)i.Element("id"),
                                        name = (string)i.Element("name"),                                       
                                        rating = (int)i.Element("rating_count")
                                    }).ToList(),
                         popular_shelves = (from i in u.Elements("popular_shelves").Elements("shelf")
                                            select new
                                            {
                                                name = (string)i.Attribute("name"),
                                                count = (int)i.Attribute("count")
                                            }).ToList(),

                     }).ToList();
```

The code returns null values and is not working properly. I also should note that different xml files may not have values for all the tags.

Any suggestions on how I can improve my code?

Comment: there is a missing `</author>` tag If I am not mistaken.

Comment: yeah, you're correct. edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for missing elements like such:

```
name = i.Element("name") == null ? null : i.Element("name")
```

For value types, you make have to change them to nullable types for this to work correctly.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I still got "Value cannot be null." error. there are two type of tags with the name of "book". The first one is the parent of other book in similar_books tags, which I think maybe the reason of error.... any suggestion?

Comment: I want to store some of the tags info in DB

Comment: You are trying to cast a null value to an int/string. you need to check to see if the element exists before you cast

Comment: Yeah, but lets say the tag of popular_shelves is only for the first book descendant not for the rest, how can I check that? it is not only about the value but also the the tag itself

Comment: You will have to separate your parsing code out into separate lines, then check if those parent elements have any child elements to parse.

Comment: your answer along with below answer is the complete one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can transform

```
id = (int)i.Element("id"),
```

to

```
id = (int?)i.Element("id"),
```

Whole modified code

```
// I am inserting the following line to demonstrate how I load the XML in test code
// Basically, I copied & pasted xml in a file OP gave named request.xml
//XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load( @"d:\Data\request.xml");
```

**EDIT**

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("http://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn?isbn=0007295685&key=lbScLXWyNGQ1q0BDoFFSg");

var books = (from u in xdoc.Descendants().Elements("book")
                select new
                {

                    id = (string)u.Element("title"),
                    title = (string)u.Element("title"),
                    works = (from i in u.Elements("work")
                            select new
                            {
                                work_best_book_id = (int?)i.Element("id"),
                                work_name = (string)i.Element("name"),

                            }).ToList(),
                    authors = (from i in u.Elements("authors").Elements("author")
                            select new
                            {
                                id = (int?)i.Element("id"),
                                name = (string)i.Element("name"),
                                rating = (int?)i.Element("rating_count")
                            }).ToList(),
                    popular_shelves = (from i in u.Elements("popular_shelves").Elements("shelf")
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        name = (string)i.Attribute("name"),
                                        count = (int?)i.Attribute("count")
                                    }).ToList(),

                }).ToList();
```

Comment: now this error comes up:Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @MT467 I used xml you gave(by fixing missing `</author>` tag) and modified the code as I indicated in my answer. I obtained a list having two elements(The Yiddish Policemen's Union & Stations of Tide) Perhaps you have given us a partial XML and in the real XML file you are using there is a string that needs to be reformatted. Did you try to debug ? In which statement the code fails to cast ? What is the data at the moment the code fails?

Comment: try with this url :http://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn?isbn=0007295685&key=lbScLXWyNGQ1q0BDoFFSg

Comment: @MT467 No crash. This time I have a list with 6 books. Which means your problem comes from this line `XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(responseReader.ReadToEnd());` because this is the only part that is different for your code and mine _(please see updated post to see how I load the file and try the same on your side)_

Comment: @MT467 edited again the post to load from the link you gave **only for test purposes**. Same result and no crash! _(though I am doubtful about passing hard coded url's in this method, I modified by keeping the old one commented )_

Comment: I still got error!!!, I also updated the code part that I am using to load xDocument. I need to use proxy so I cant use load directly??(not sure)

Comment: @MT467 sorry to hear that. I don't know how I can help you further. Please look @ [this link](http://mechanicalobject.com/Images/ml-parsing-with-linq-has-2-tags.png)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. your code is working now:) so I'd like to give answer both to you and the above answer

Comment: @MT467 You cannot mark 2 posts as answer.chose the post That You find most useful